# Spark Streaming HDFS starting job with existing data

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I am building a dStream from an HDFS path using:

```
val myDstream=ssc.textFileStream(inputPath)
```

As expected, the dStream reads every new file that is written (moved) into the HDFS path **while the app is running**. However, it does not process files which were allready there when the application started up

When I restart the application after modifying its code, I would like to reread the old files that are already in the path. I would also like it to read new files that were uploaded as the application was restarted (this can take ~30 seconds of downtime).

At startup I would to process the entire path, and **then** go on to stream new files.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If the business problem that you're trying to solve is event processing, perhaps something like Kafka would be a more appropriate place to queue events. Spark Streaming can be a subscriber of the queue and another subscriber can simultaneously store the events into HDFS for later batch processing.

Comment: I will eventually use Kafka, I'm using HDFS now because it's allready setup . However even with a kafka source, the question remains: I want to update my processor code (let's say it had a bug), I now want to re-process old data first before reading the newer events. How do I load that data into the dStream before processing newer events? Is there a design pattern here?

Comment: You can apparently tell Kafka to start at the beginning of the queue by giving it an offset: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#simpleconsumerapi

Comment: As far as I remember, kafka does not persist messages indefinitly after they are consumed. As such, messages that were read by the buggy code could be lost forever.

Comment: In that case, I would try using core Spark re-using the relevant logic in your Spark Streaming code to do batch processing on the messages archived in HDFS directly.